# Firefox is not displaying some Indian fonts correctly

Tags: firefox

[image]

What should I do ? i have ubuntu 16.04  and firefox 51
I don't have the problem in Chromium.

Comment: Are you maybe using a font that doesn't contain all character glyphs you need? Try to choose another font in Firefox's settings (`about:preferences` -> Content).

Comment: I changed the font to Ubuntu from Serif. The issue still persists.

Comment: Go to the page source (Ctrl+U) and find the text encoding (Charset= ??). Then set the text encoding (View --> Text Encoding) to be the same. You should add Ubuntu and FF versions to your question.

Comment: Text encoding is unicode. charset is utf-8. I dont know how to set text encoding to that.

Comment: Which Indian language are you trying to use in Firefox? I can see Firefox is not displaying some of the languages, but I can't see which ones.